# debugging with console mode

Tags: ios

How can I activate the console mode when I build and run my iOS application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode4 choose "XCode" on the top menu and under preferences -> behaviors you can specify which information comes up when you build and run.  You can also manually bring up the console by opening the lower panel with the view controls on the right of the project window or with the log history tab on the left.

In previous versions of Xcode you can access the console from one of the top menus by choosing "Run Console"  You can also specify that the console start automatically on a build and run through the preferences like in 4.